# limit of a simple complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that the function $f(x+iy) = 3xy + i(3y - x^3-3x^2)$ is differentiable at the point $x+iy$ such that $(x, y) = (0, 1),$

---

So I have started by considering the limit $$\lim_{x+iy\to i}\dfrac{f(x+iy) - f(i)}{x+i(y-1)} = \lim_{x+iy\to i} \dfrac{3xy + i(3y-x^3-3x^2)}{x+i(y-1)}$$

Now I'm not sure how to progress here. Maybe this is not the best route? Possibly could use the Cauchy Riemann equations.

Comment: do you know the cauchy riemann equations?

Comment: Yes, how can I use them?

Comment: ِYou've missed "$-3i$" in nominator of the second fraction for $-f(i)$. And in sequel of your limit computation you can multiple complex conjugate of denominator to denom and nomin of your fraction, then following using lHopital.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ where $u$ and $v$ are real valued functions, is differentiable at $a+ib$ if and only if $u$ and $v$ be continuously differentiable at $(a,b)$ and Cauchy-Riemann equations at this point be satisfied. Obviously first condition is valid for your function so let's check the second part.

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=3y,\quad \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=3$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=3x,\quad -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-(x^2-2x)$$

Now
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\Longrightarrow y=1$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\Longrightarrow x\in\{0,1\}$$

Which $(x,y)=(0,1)$ of your question is here too.